# Magento 2: Layered navigation sidebar filter search query customization

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, filter

I want to customize the query  like ?product_type=64  I want to add more attribute in query .
I just actually want filter works only on configurable pre-select value not all products which have that attribute.

Is there any way to do like that?